# Advantages of spray vs roller system for painting a flat

Tags: painting, tools

I'm getting ready to start renovating an old flat, which for some time had subtenants, then some friends living in it for some time, then subtenants again and so on... It is not in a bad condition, just requires some freshing up - walls painting, some floor renovations (ok, this will probably wait), replacement of electrical sockets, that kind of thing...

My question is with regards to wall painting. So far I've always painted walls with rollers. Nowadays I see on the web, that [spray systems also exist](http://www.bosch-wallpaint.com/za/en/paint-spray-system) that seem to result in a nicer job.

I'm interested, what would be the advantages of such systems over roller application of paint, and is it worth it? I'm interested in painting the walls in a nice white, but would like to get a relatively "smooth" (fine) finish, not something rough.

Answer (score 2):

Sprayers are capable of giving a very smooth finish very quickly. That is why you will often see professionals use sprayers when finishing trim, stairs and cabinets. The negatives of a sprayer would be the amount of prep time required to start painting. You have to tape and plastic EVERYTHING. Do not underestimate the amount of over and back spray you will get from a sprayer.

Also keep in mind if the walls aren't smooth right now, spraying over them won't make them smooth. You'll need to sand them down before applying your coating. You can also get a relatively smooth finish with the right roller and pan if you spend enough time sanding and prepping your surfaces.

Comment: If the flat is completely empty, it's all going to be one color and it's fully carpeted (but you plan to replace the carpet) spraying might make sense (and then replace the paint-splattered old carpet after painting.) Choice of appropriate roller covers and paint will do a smooth job and requires far less prep time, while being much easier to manage multiple colors, etc.

Comment: @Ecnerwal - There are no carpets in the flat, but parquet (wooden boards). I would like to avoid replacing them completely, but I can cover them with old newspapers or the like to avoid spraying over them. Would that do?